# datediff MySQL between one particular date and a column

Tags: mysql, datediff

I have date column in dd-mm-yyyy as below:

```
| xdate |
----------
| 30-07-2001 |
| 21-09-2003 |
| 16-06-2020 |
```

How to calculate date difference between one particular date say from '2021-11-10' to xdate column and represent in years, months, and days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dd-mm-yyyy` is not a valid `MySQL` datetime format. I will suggest that you always store dates in datetime types.

A simple solution for your  case , maybe not the optimal for the performance on large data would be :

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2021-11-10',date_format(str_to_date(xdate,'%d-%m-%Y'),'%Y-%m-%d')) AS days
FROM test_tbl;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/127

For MONTHS and YEARS you can try:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, date_format(str_to_date(xdate, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d'),'2021-11-10' ) AS months
FROM test_tbl;


SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_format(str_to_date(xdate, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d'),'2021-11-10' ) AS years
FROM test_tbl;
```

DEMO: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/129

> More on DATEDIFF:
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff
>
> You can use TIMESTAMPDIFF if you want MONTH , YEAR...
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff